# PHP Sum up JSON Object value

Tags: php, json

I know this sounds silly but how do I get the total sum of all the object's total?

My json decode format looks something like this:

```
Array
(
[results] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [total] => 22   
            )
        [1] => Array
            ( 
                [total] => 10
            )
     )
)
```

I've tried using writing something like this but it shows "Trying to get property of non-object in..."

```
echo 'Array Total<pre>';
$sum = 0;
foreach ( $receipt_data['results'] as $receipt )
{
    $sum += $receipt->total;
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it's works for you
You have array so you need to use array instead of object.

```
echo 'Array Total<pre>';
$sum = 0;
foreach ( $receipt_data['results'] as $receipt )
{
    $sum += $receipt['total'];
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: sorry remove [0] and check

Comment: if you direct use $receipt_data instead of $receipt_data['results'] then you need to use [0]